# Linux user permissions for Django deployment

Tags: linux, django, security, deployment, permissions

Let's say a Django site lives on a production server in `/var/virtualenvs/sitename` with a directory structure like this:

```
/var/virtualenvs/sitename/
    logs/
        access.log
        error.log
        ...
    media/
        ...
    src/
        app_1/
        app_2/
        django_project_name/
            manage.py
            django_project_name/
                settings.py
                urls.py
                wsgi.py
    static/
        ...
```

What's the best way to assign ownership and permissions for these files in a secure production environment?

Assume the setup uses nginx as a reverse proxy and Gunicorn as a Django service (though general answers applying to other tools would help, too).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943633/best-practices-for-linux-user-permissions-to-run-web-application-as